# the memory usage of my .csv file in pandas is bigger than my RAM. how is this possible?

Tags: python, pandas, memory

Please help me understand. I have 4 GB of RAM. I read in a full csv file that is 2.1GB large in pandas using

```
data = pd.read_csv('~/data.csv')
```

Now when I check the memory usage of the file with the following code:

```
data.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
```

It returns 6012181982 bytes or 6GB. How is it possible that the memory usage is larger than my actual RAM and I won't get any memory errors?

Comment: What happens if you remove `sum()`? : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html

Comment: @PedroLobito In that case I just get the memory usage per column (23 in my case). Adding those up equal the 6 GB.

Comment: Not every object is being used at runtime.